# Add a short code to a plugin

Tags: shortcode

I'm looking to extend a few plugins by adding custom shortcodes.
These plugins  create front-end pages, but I want to display that page content on another page. 
I figure there's an easy way to just take the entire php file that outputs the page data and wrap it in a function, but I'm not really sure how to start - where I should include the shortcode function and how I can get it to return the generated file. 
Thoughts?

(Eg: sabaidirectory create a directory dashboard page that solely outputs 'dashboard.php' to site.com/dashboard - I want that entire page to show up wherever I use [sabai-dashboard])

Comment: Do you know how to create shortcodes?

Comment: I know how to create one in functions.php (but thst includes pasting all the code  there), not sure how to register one that uses the php from somewhere else.

Comment: Have you tried using  a shortcode using include(); ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code that you need to pull content from a wordpress page you will require the id number of the page and add it into the shortcode.
[example page_id="21"][/example]

```
function example_shortcode( $atts, $content = null) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                'page_id' => ''
            ), $atts 
        ) 
    );
    // Will display our page content of the shortcode need a number of the page id

      $post = get_post($page_id); 
      $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
      echo $content;  

}
add_shortcode('example', 'example_shortcode'); 

//[example page_id="page id number here"][/example]
```

Comment: Please use one account only